# Java: Difficulty assigning to generic from wildcard generic

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I am new to wildcards and relatively inexperienced with generics in Java, and I am running into an issue assigning them.

I have a custom generic class called `UserVariable<T>`.  Each UserVariable knows two things about itself: its Type and its Value, both of which are expected at the time it is constructed.  A barebones definition looks like this:

```
class UserVariable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<UserVariable<T>>
{

private T value;
private final transient Class<T> type;

public UserVariable(T value, Class<T> type)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
}

public T getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public Class<T> getType()
{
    return type;
}

}
```

I have a collection of these UserVariables stored in a Map.  I've used a wildcard in defining the Map so that I can store UserVariables of various types all in one Map.  The idea here is that the user of my software is creating variables and giving them names, and the software can store/look up the variables in the Map using the variable name as the key:

```
class VarsMap {

private ObservableMap<String, UserVariable<?>> userVars = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

public void setVariable(String name, UserVariable<?> variable)
{
    userVars.put(name, variable);
}

public UserVariable<?> getVariable(String name)
{
    return userVars.get(name);
}

}
```

Later, I have a class that tries to retrieve one of this variables and store its type.  I am having trouble with the very last assignment...

```
class SimpleComparison<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private StringProperty variableName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
private T comparisonValue;
private transient Class<T> myVarType;

public SimpleComparison(String variableName, T value, VarsMap theVars)
{
    this.myVarType = theVars.getVariable(variableName).getType();  //error here
}

}
```

`this.myVarType` is defined as a `Class<T>` and `UserVariable<T>`'s `getType()` method should return a `Class<T>`.  Also, the `type` for each `UserVariable` is stored at the time each `UserVariable` is constructed.  However, the last assignment give the following error:

Type Mismatch: cannot convert from `Class<capture#1-of ?>` to `Class<T>`

Perhaps this is because the Map is a map of `UserVariable<?>`?  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks for your help!

Edit: Ultimately what I would like to do is have a method in `SimpleComparison` called `evaluate` that does this:

```
public int evaluate(VarsMap theVars)
{
    UserVariable<T> lhs = theVars.getVariable(variableName);
    UserVariable<T> rhs = new UserVariable<T>(comparisonValue, myVarType);

    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
}
```

That is, I construct a `SimpleComparison` object using a variable name and a value to compare to.  Later I call `evaluate` on that object, passing in the Map of current variable values, and it compares the current value of the variable (taken from the Map) to the comparison value that was passed in at construction time, and returns the result.

However, I'm not sure the call to `compareTo` will work because `lhs` will want to be of type `Class<?>` while `rhs` will be of type `Class<T>`.  Is there a way to do this the way I'm intending?  Or will the type of the object always be lost when I drop it into a container of wildcard objects (the Map in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are strictly checked by the compiler. So, as far as you maintain each generic instantiation related onyl to other instatiations for the same type, everything is fine:

```
MyGeneric<String> s1=...
MyOtherGeneric<String> o1=...
s1.doSomething(o1);
```

The problem comes when you try to mix types:

```
MyGeneric<String> s1=...
MyOtherGeneric<Double> o1=...
s1.doSomething(o1);    // Error
```

Ok, this is pretty obvious. In your case, the problem is similar: You try to collect several generic instantiations no-matter-which-type-they-are-based-on into a non-generic abstraction `VarsMap`.

So, when you try to mix up an object contained in the non-generic abstraction `VarsMap` with a generic object `Class<T>`, how can the compiler determine if their types match or not? Then a compiler error arises.

The simplest solution I see: Since you are already matching the `UserVariable` objects by name, and I suppose that each variable has always the same type, you can rely in this program-made checking and assume that their types will match: Simply add a method-scoped parameter to the method `getVariable` and a simple cast:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> UserVariable<T> getVariable(String name)
{
    return (UserVariable<T>)this.userVars.get(name);
}
```

... and also add the proper type parameter substitution wherever you call it:

```
this.myVarType=theVars.<T> getVariable(variableName).getType();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your map contains values with different type parameters (you can store `Class<Integer>`, `Class<String>` and etc) and when you get the value from the map you don't know what type parameter the value has and compiler raises an error because you can't cast to `Class<T>` values with type parameters different from `T` (but you can explicitly cast to `Class<T>` by `(Class<T>) theVars.getVariable(variableName).getType()` with compiler warning of unsafe cast).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added a follow-up question to my original post.  Do you know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: For instance, while you can't know what the type parameter is when you get it from the map, the object itself knows its own type, since it stored it as a private variable at construction time, right?  Is it possible to utilize that information?